# symfony unable to create cache dir on docker

Tags: php, symfony, docker, caching

i make a docker-compose to my symfony application, it works, but it throw me a permissions error when the app try to create the cache directory:

this is my docker-compose file:

```
nginx:
      image: nginx:1.15-alpine
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
        - "8000:80"
      volumes:
        - .:/app:delegated
        - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      depends_on:
        - php

    php:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
        - "9030:9001"
      volumes:
        - .:/app:delegated
```

and this is my php dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:1.8 AS vendor

COPY composer.json composer.lock /app/

RUN composer install \
     --ignore-platform-reqs \
        --no-interaction \
        --no-plugins \
        --no-scripts \
        --prefer-dist

FROM php:7-fpm-alpine3.8
WORKDIR /app
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets mysqli mbstring bcmath pdo_mysql pdo
COPY . /var/www/html/app
COPY --from=vendor ./app/vendor/ /var/www/html/app/vendor/
COPY ./docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini

EXPOSE 80
```

this throw me this error when i enter to localhost:8000

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory (/app/app/cache/prod) in /app/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2725 Stack trace: #0 /app/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2686): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() #1 /app/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2465): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() #2 /app/app/AppKernel.php(19): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() #3 /app/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2496): AppKernel->boot() #4 /app/web/app.php(28): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #5 {main} thrown in /app/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2725
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

User responsible for create cache directory doesn't have permissions to do it.

You can try to add to your Dockerfile

```
RUN setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX ./app/cache ./app/logs
RUN setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX ./app/cache ./app/logs
```

You can also run this on your host if you are Linux user:

`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R app/cache/ app/logs/`

Comment: hi, sorry for the delay. I tried adding RUN apk add acl, and these two setfacl commands, but the problem persist, the message is the same :/

Comment: the cache directory after run these commands have this permissions:

drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 Mar 21 21:02 cache

Comment: and the logs directory has : drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     xfs           4096 Mar 19 17:48 logs